# Трэкер увеличивает маршрут на пару лишних км, при переключении на другие спутники

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

Идешь с телефоном пишешь трек поворачиваешь по улице на 90 градусов и твой маршрут в месте после поворота начинает вырисовывать кренделя, и вместо 1600 метров маршрут становится 4200 метров, после того как развернулся обратно на 90 градусов и получается идешь по старому направлению по параллельной улице, датчик вновь видит правильные спутники и корректно отображает маршрут.

1. Что делать когда телефон отворачивается от спутников за которыми
   он следит, как не допустить метание трека? (понятно что фильтровать GPS координаты, но фильтры используемые в Open GPS Tracker не помогают, где взять нормальные?)
2. Я выбирал образец трэкера между Open GPS Tracker и Мои Треки от google (тогда я подумал что это лучшие из лучших, может я не прав), на тесте Open GPS Tracker дал более точные результаты и я использовал [Open GPS Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker) как образец, запустил самописный трэкер и его, оба выдали ошибку в месте поворота на несколько километров. В сети вообще есть пример адекватного трэкера?

Похоже что просто, gps датчик у моего дешового lenovo полное г.

Comment: Если все правильно настроино дуолно работать. Попробуйте не брать данные когда спутники < 3. И еще что бы оценить вашу задачу, покажите код как вы сделали листенер

Comment: Да вы правы, надо было лучше в настройках разобраться.